# Calculate the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x-\cos(x^2+y^2)-\arctan(x)+1}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Find the limit, $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x-\cos(x^2+y^2)-\arctan(x)+1}{x^2+y^2}.$$

My attempt:

I have tried several paths for evaluating the limit. For instance, $y=0$, $x=0$, $y=x$, $x=\tan y$, etc. I always obtain $0$. But I haven't been able to prove that the limit is equal to $0$.

Comment: Hint: $|x-\arctan(x)|\leq |x|^3$ and $|1-\cos(x)|\leq \frac{x^2}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following limits which you can easily show using Taylor or L'Hosp.:

- $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1-\cos t}{t^2}=\frac 12$, hence, $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1-\cos t}{t}=0$
- $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\arctan x}{x^2}=0$

Now, just rewrite the given expression as follows:

\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{x-\cos(x^2+y^2)-\arctan(x)+1}{x^2+y^2}
& = & \underbrace{\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}}_{\stackrel{(x,y)\to (0,0)}{\longrightarrow}0} + \underbrace{\frac{x-\arctan x}{x^2+y^2}}_{\left|\frac{x-\arctan x}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq\left|\frac{x-\arctan x}{x^2}\right|\stackrel{(x,y)\to (0,0)}{\longrightarrow}0} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

The magic words are: polar coordinate. The limit equals:

$$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{r \cos \theta - \cos{r^2}  - \arctan{ r \cos \theta} +1}{r^2}.$$

Now $1-\cos r^2 = O(r^4),$ so that part goes to zero, and $\arctan r \cos \theta - r \cos \theta = O(r^3),$ so that goes to zero also.

Comment: To add on, in general, when I see some $x^2+y^2$ terms, my first attempt is using polar coordinates.